# RDS ENV variables in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I asked this question already in aws forum:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254834&tstart=0

I have a docker container, that expects certain env variables. How do i inject in the RDS env variables to the docker container?

RDS env variables are:

- RDS_HOSTNAME – The hostname of the DB instance. Amazon RDS console
  label – Endpoint combines hostname and port.
- RDS_PORT – The port on
  which the DB instance accepts connections. The default value varies
  between DB engines.
- RDS_DB_NAME  The database name, ebdb. 
  – DB Name RDS_USERNAME The user name that you configured for your database.
- RDS_PASSWORD – The password that you
  configured for your database.

My docker json file is like so:

```
    {
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "volumes": [],
    "containerDefinitions": [{
            "name": "pact",
            "image": "dius/pact_broker",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [{
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 80
            }],
            "environment": [{
                    "name": "PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME",
                    "value": "pactbroker"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "TheUserPassword"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST",
                    "value": "localhost"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME",
                    "value": "pactbrokeruser"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": []
        }
    ]
}
```